# property text not found on object of type nstextfield

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm making simple SQLite database for MacOS and use information from [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_%28Xcode_4%29) tutorial which is for iOS.

I got an error "property text not found on object of type nstextfield" when I implement these lines of code:

```
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS 
    (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", 
    name.text, address.text, phone.text];
```

How can I implement this for MacOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use the `stringValue` property of the NSTextField (NSControl from which the NSTextField inherits):
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSControl

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS 
(name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", 
name.stringValue, address.stringValue, phone.stringValue];
```